Constructing Shortest and Longest (Longest Increasing Subsequence)
Source: Codeforces
Question summary:
We are given sequences of < and >, where a < b means b is greater than a and a > b means b is less than a. From the $<>$s, we must construct two sequence of numbers from $1$ to $n$ that respectfully produce the longest and shortest LIS (longest increasing subsequence).
Eg:

$<<< $ has one answer $1<2<3$ for both longest and shortest
$>>> $ has one answer $3>2>1$ for both longest and shortest
$>><>>< $ has one possible answer:

$\textbf{5}>4>3<\textbf{7}>2>1<6$ for shortest LIS of length $2$ ($[5,7],[5,6],[4,7],[4,6]\dots$)

$4>3>\textbf{1}<7>\textbf{5}>2<\textbf{6}$ for longest LIS of length $3$ ($[1,2,6], [1,5,6],[4,5,6]\dots$)




I can see that the longest contiguous block of $<$ in any sequence will be the minimum length for LIS. For example, $(1<2<3<4)>>>>><>$ will have at least $4$ elements as the shortest LIS.
The tutorial suggests for longest LIS:

Let's group each contiguously decreasing part. We can easily see that there can be at most one element from each group that is included in any possible LIS. It can be shown that we can make a sequence that takes one element from every groups to form the LIS.


One strategy is to fill the smallest unused numbers in decreasing order for each group from left to right. Then for every indices  and  where  and  are in different groups, [] will be always greater than []. Thus, we can take any one element from each and every groups to form the LIS.

For example, they would group $>$ in $(>>)<(>>)< $ to make $(3>2>\textbf{1})<(6>\textbf{5}>4)<\textbf{7}$.
I don't understand why this would yield the longest LIS.

There are two statements: 1) any IS includes at most one element of each group; 2) there is an IS that includes one element from each group. Which part you need?

@mihaild, the second one. The first one is fairly trivial because it is a decreasing subsequence.

Because with proposed strategy every number from left group is less than any number from right. So, taking one arbitrary element from each group will give you IS.

@mihaild Yes but how does that lead to the longest LIS?

This gives the IS with length equal to number of groups. And by 1, any IS has at most that many elements. Thus, this gives the longest IS.
